Linux Samba share is logging a lot of failed logins because it's using the VPN creds instead of Active Directory
I have a Linux device (QNAP NAS) that is serving a Samba share and uses Active Directory for authentication. It works seamlessly locally, but when users are working from home over a VPN, the VPN credentials are being used to authenticate first I think because the failed login attempt logs are flooded with entries, but the users are not reporting any issues connecting.
Is there a way for me to fix this on either end?
I have checked credential manager and tried removing the credentials for the server, but they just get added back again.
Clients: Windows 11
(QNAP support is useless)

Just as I was finishing up this question, I found the answer here:
https://community.spiceworks.com/t/prompted-for-credentials-accessing-mapped-drive-on-vpn/768119/7?u=spiceuser-jx1ik
By default, my VPN connection was configured to "UseRasCredentials".
This did not affect Windows shares, but did affect my Linux Samba shares, resulting in trying to connect to the Samba share using the VPN credentials. I found two ways to fix this. I could Enable NPS on Windows Server and authenticate with the VPN through it, or modify a character in the settings of the VPN connection file. The latter has lower overhead. The file can be found at:
User:
%AppData%\Microsoft\Network\Connections\Pbk\rasphone.pbk
System:
%ProgramData%\Microsoft\Network\Connections\Pbk\rasphone.pbk
simply open in notepad and modify UseRasCredentials=1 to 0
I wrote a script to automate this, but you need to edit this file for each user with a VPN connection.
This PS script is written to be run in the user context, but request admin creds if not found to access the system path.
<#
    Block the VPN Credentials from being used for network resources i.e. Linux Samba share to keep the server logs clean
    First checks if the VPN connection settings file is in the user's profile, otherwise checks the system.
    Then replaces UseRasCredentials=1 with a 0.
    Requests admin creds if a system file.
    AUTHOR: TheCodeGeek
#>

$pbkpath = Join-Path $env:APPDATA 'Microsoft\Network\Connections\Pbk\rasphone.pbk'
if ((Test-Path -Path $pbkpath) -ne $true) {
    $pbkpath = Join-Path $env:PROGRAMDATA "Microsoft\Network\Connections\Pbk\rasphone.pbk"
}
try {
    (Get-Content -path $pbkpath -Raw) -Replace 'UseRasCredentials=1','UseRasCredentials=0' | Set-Content -path $pbkpath -ErrorAction Stop
}
catch {
    Start-Process Powershell -ArgumentList "-ExecutionPolicy Bypass -NoProfile -File $PSCommandPath" -Verb RunAs
}


Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers in the help center.
